# Block all inappropriate words in the textbox when click button

Tags: javascript, html

Below is my code which show me notice of inserting kill , fight, slap when i insert in the textbox.
But i want to block all inappropriate words possible in the textbox like f**k and so on. DO you guys have any ideas. Thanks

```
       <html>  
       <head>  
       <meta charset="utf-8" />  
       <title></title>  
       </head>  
       <body>  
       <div id="wrapper" style="width:600px; margin:0 auto;">  
        <h2></h2>  
        <input id="txtWords" style="width:300px;" />  

        <br />  
        <input type="button" id="btnCheck" onclick="fnCheckForRestrictedWords();" value="Check For 
       Restricted Words">  
        </div>  
        <script type="text/javascript">  
        function fnCheckForRestrictedWords() {  
            var restrictedWords = new Array("kill", "fight", "slap");  
            var txtInput = document.getElementById("txtWords").value;  
            var error = 0;  
            for (var i = 0; i < restrictedWords.length; i++) {  
                var val = restrictedWords[i];  
                if ((txtInput.toLowerCase()).indexOf(val.toString()) > -1) {  
                    error = error + 1;  
                }  
            }  

            if (error > 0) {  
                alert('You have entered some restricted words.')  
            }  
            else {  
                // Your logic here  
            }  
         }  
        </script>  

       </body>  
      </html>
```

Comment: In principal this isn't possible. There are just too many words and different ways to write them or add punctuation etc etc. But there is a package called bad-words which might help you: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bad-words

Answer (score 1):

You need to define all "bad" words and put them in your blacklist. You can use some existing lists as a starting point for your list:

https://github.com/LDNOOBW/List-of-Dirty-Naughty-Obscene-and-Otherwise-Bad-Words/blob/master/en

https://github.com/dariusk/wordfilter/blob/master/lib/badwords.json

http://www.bannedwordlist.com/lists/swearWords.txt

http://www.frontgatemedia.com/new/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Terms-to-Block.csv

Source: [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Twitch/comments/6jdsco/is_there_a_text_file_with_all_the_blacklisted/)

If you want to include obfuscated "bad" words you may need to add the to the list as well.

Answer (score 0):

The

```js
includes()
```

method should work: txtInput.includes(restrictedWords[i]) which returns either true or false. You also want to include more bad words and different ways to write them